# Are there probability distributions with $\text{Mean}(x) = e / 4$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As the question suggests, are there any known probabilities that have some of their metrics assosiated with $e$? and also what can be inferred about some sample which has a mean of $\frac{e}{4}$.

Comment: You can make the mean anything you like.  Just knowing the mean doesn't tell us much about the distribution.

Comment: oh, So just to clarify - if i collect some sample, and the mean of the sample converges on e  the larger the sample, there is noting associated with this?

Comment: If you have a sample with  mean $\mu$ then just adding $e-\mu$ to each term gives you a sample with mean $e$.  So, nothing special.

Comment: This is a legitimate question if it is reworded slightly. Is there a distribution with rational parameters whose mean involves $e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [it is claimed that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Occurrence_and_applications) the [log normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) occurs often "in the wild," and the mean of a log-normally distributed random variable with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is $e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$.  In particular, the $\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$ version has mean $\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

For example:
$$\text{Binomial}(16,\frac{e}{64})$$
We know for binomial distribution the mean equals $\mu=n\cdot p$, so:
$$\mu=16\cdot\frac{e}{64}=\frac{e}{4}.$$
Here you have a distribution with mean $\frac{e}{4}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was what your question was about, tell me if not.

Comment: Not really, my question was, lets say i collect data about some process and i take interval measurements, when i calculate the mean, the mean is some multiple of the number e. are there any such known examples where some natural/ non natural process produces observations which have a mean which is a multiple of e?

Comment: @dvd280 Oh okay, I see. Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: its fine if you dont, i dont mind.